# Transactional email tracking with Amason SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, transactional-email

I have set up an Amazon SES account to send my transactional mail. It looks like working good.
But I need to track remote server response of each of email (when it is send, delivered and accepted by the server)
In this document they suggest some alternatives http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html

Thru the alternatives I gave a try to  Amazon CloudWatch. Cloudwatch started giving me some information at the overall but not at the email detail (delivery time, etc)

Anybody can help me in this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get detail information of individual email using Cloudwatch. For that, you will have to incorporate SNS together with SES.

This will help you to understand how it should be done: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-add-event-destination-sns.html